# Connect the build.number variable with a configuration parameter

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build-server, implemented with team-city.
Until now, I have an input parameter that represent the first 3 parts of the version number (x.y.z) = %Version.Number%

When I compile my exe files, I set the file version to be:
%Version.Number%.%build_number% and then I get a 4 parts version number.

The problem with that solution is that there is no connection between the first 3 parts of the version number and the build number.

Now, I want to find a way to have a different set of %build_number% for each %Version.Number%.

I will illustrate the problem with an example:

On the first build when %Version.Number% = 15.3.2 - the version number will be 15.3.2.0 .

On the second build when %Version.Number% = 15.3.2 - the version number will be 15.3.2.1 .

Now, on a new build when %Version.Number% = 16.0.0 - the version number will be 16.0.0.2
and I want to be 16.0.0.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to handle this, at least:

- Use the **[Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin)** -
  it will allow you to reset the "running" build number whenever you like -
  simply set the next-build-number to '1' whenever the major release is increased
  (as a bonus, it also lets you format the version-number with leading-zeroes and such).
- Create a new job whenever you increase the major release number -

  1. copy build_job_15.3.2 to build_job_16.0.0
  2. edit the version-number in build_job_16.0.0 to be '16.0.0'
  3. optional: disable build_job_15.3.2

  Now you can run build_job_16.0.0, and the build number will start with '1'
  (this method is a bit tedious, but allows you to continue building 15.3.2 releases, if needed).

Comment: Are those ways relevant to Team-City build server as well?

Comment: Will answer with a question: Can you "inject" a version-number to Team-City? (in other words: If Team-City will accept a parameter from Jenkins that is the version-number, then you are OK, but if Team-City is setting its own version-number, then this will not work).

Answer (score 1):

You are able to reset the build number counter in the General Settings of the Build Configuration. Is that not sufficient for your scenario?

Comment: I don't want someone (probably be me :) ) to click on this link on every new major version. In addition, I want to be able to build an old major version and give it the last build number of that version plus 1.